# Fake Stack Overflow clone sites

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Are the clone sites listed below affiliated with Stack Overflow and if they aren't, is it possible to get them shut down?  They look like phishing websites to me.

https://krom.cryptoo.online/

http://resolved-error.com/

Comment: Yeah - [Shut 'em down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwBMv-YdqYM) ;)

Comment: At least those ones don't have addresses that almost match SO. I embarrassingly almost fell for logging into a fake site because it ranked very high on Google and had an address like stakoverflow.com. I only caught it because I found it odd that I wasn't already logged in.

Comment: Should we give them Google juice here??

Comment: I'm assuming the SE team is aware of these, right? @animuson

Comment: @animuson Here's another one: https://stackoverflow.gw-proxy.com